# Two matrices with same eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have two $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$. They have the same eigenvectors but not necessarily the same eigenvalues and both of them are diagonalizable. I want to show that for any real numbers $c$ and $d$, $E=cA+dB$ is also diagonalizable.

My question is:

Even though they have same eigenvectors, does not the order in which the eigenvectors are put determine what diagonalizing matrix they have? Or in other words, do they need to have same diagonalizing matrix? How do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be a matrix containing the eigenvectors (of which there are $n$, where these are $n \times n$ matrices). Then 
$$
V^{-1} A V = D_1
$$
is diagonal, as is $V^{-1} B V = D_2$. (It'd be a really good exercise for you to figure out why,)  If you now compute, you get
$$
V^{-1}(cA + dB)V = (cV^{-1}A + dV^{-1}B) V = c V^{-1}AV + dV^{-1}BV = cD_1 + dD_2
$$
which is again diagonal. $$D_{(i,i)} = cD_{1(i,i)} + dD_{2(i,i)}$$

Comment: The way I think why it should be true is because even though the two matrices have different eigen values, I can arrange them in such a manner that the corresponding diagnonalizing matrix will be same for both of them, Is that true?

Comment: Or I should not worry about the orders in which the eigen vectors are arranged in diagonalizing matrix, because I can easily change the position of eigen values in the diagonal matrices D1 and D2.

Comment: Once you pick the eigenvectors and put them in $V$, the corresponding eigenvalues will show up, in $V^{-1}AV$ and $V^{-1}BV$, at the corresponding places. You really *should* work out that exercise I mentioned in the middle...if you actually want to understand, I mean.

Comment: Oh yeah. I understand that part. My only confusion was why V should be the same for both A and B. and I think you have made it clear.